# Oracle equivalent to PostGres "pg_copy_from"

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any equivalent to the function "pg_copy_from" in an Oracle database? or at least how can I insert in bulk all the entries that will be in an array?

I got from the pg_copy_from that internally it does a SQL COPY FROM. But from the syntaxis of that query I get that you need to put the database and not an array?

Comment: Where is the array stored? You can use INSERT ALL in Oracle SQL, but that doesn't work with arrays (arrays aren't an SQL concept). There might be a way with PL/SQL...

Comment: It will be created from certain data in php, thtat's why I was looking for some similar method in an oracle db to store all that info (more or less 40k entries in the array)